# JavaScript - Pass selected drop down list value to method

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

This may be a simple thing, but I am trying to capture the selected value from a drop down list on an JSP page and use the selected value as an argument to a method. I am able to use the onchange event in the select tag to call a java script function and capture the value but I am not sure how to send the value to the method. I think there is a way to do this via an ajax based call but I am not sure how to accomplish this. Here is a sample of the test code I am using. Thank you.

```
function getSelected()
  {
    var selectedSource = document.getElementById("myselect").value;
        console.log(selectedSource);
  }


<select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="getSelected();">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged in java, seems to be the wrong language. Java doesn't define variables with var or methods as functions

Comment: This is actually HTML and Javascript.

Comment: **how to send the value to the method**, and where exactly that method belongs to? client side script or server side java servlets/jsp?

Answer (score 1):

I edited the answer to include the post to the server using jQuery.

There are two errors in your javascript function:

- First, you call `getselected()`, but the function name is `getSelectedSource()`;
- Second, you try to find `sourceSystem`, but your id is `myselect`.

Make a HTTP Post using jQuery and send a parameter `myselect`, for example, with value  `selectedSource`.

In your servlet, you can get this parameter using `request.getParameter("myselect")`

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
 <script>
       function getSelected()
    {
      var selectedSource = $("#myselect").val();
          console.log(selectedSource);
          $.post("test", { myselect : selectedSource},
                   function(data) {
                     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                   });              
    }
  </script>

<select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="getSelected();">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That was just an over site. I copied the wrong test function. I still am not sure how to send the captured result to the java method. Just storing it in a java variable would work as well.

Comment: Do you mean in the server?  I edited the answer to include a http post to the server. If you need help with the server code, please post your servlet code so that we can help you.